# vs2010 unit tests aborting for no reason

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

We recently had our TFS 2008 server go down. It was rebuilt with TFS 2010 server. Now, when I selected VS unit tests and run, the first few are marked as "Aborted" and the others are "Not Executed"...
This happens without any input from me.
The unit tests were working fine before the crash.
What could be causing that?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at the test report (the trx file), and see what errors it's showing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure but I have similar problem but on my local machine and with VS 2008. I cannot run some tests and have their status aborted with no reason. In the test run results I only have message "Test host process exited unexpectedly." Seems like with no reason. But I found more info on connect.microsoft.com site. The problem is my code rises StackOverflowException and it prevents the test from running. So fixing this problem heals my tests. Hope somebody it helps.
[Unit test result only shows "aborted"/"test run error" for unrecoverable errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/122554/unit-test-result-only-shows-aborted-test-run-error-for-unrecoverable-errors)

Comment: Same issue for me. I could prove this by commenting out the line that caused the `StackOverflowException`. Then the test succeeds, set a breakpoint, and on the execution of that breakpoint run the commented line in the Immediate Window. Then the debugger catches the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same issue, however in my case ALL tests were being skipped, and the error was reproducible on an empty test project, so code was ruled out.

Checking the EventViewer led me to the cause in my case; somehow the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe.config file had been removed from my machine?!? I copied one from another machine here and I'm back in action.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me and as Mike said it was because I had a stack overflow exception somewhere in my code. As soon as I fixed the SO exception the problem went away. Finding the SO exception was quite hard, but I just had to step through the code until I finally found a recursive call that would cause an SO.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered a similar problem which stopped me completely.

To get round it, firstly I ran the NUnit test via debug (TEST --> Debug --> All Tests) which allowed me to step through.

[The error was related to the use of Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455747/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name). If your project under test uses Entity Framework then the NUnit project needs a reference to EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer (or whichever provider you're using).