# Can't use a MySQL connection for entity framework 6

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use entity framework 6 with MySQL.

I did install MySQL plugin for visual studio 1.1.1 and MySQL .Net connector 6.8.3.

The problem is when I try to create a new ADO.NET Entity model, I can't choose MySQL for the connection.

[image]

But if I create a connection from the connection tool in visual studio, I can see MySQL

[image]

It means that the version currently installed is not compatible with entity framework 6. How is it possible after that I installed the latest connector and the plugin. Is there anything else to do?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I did a fresh install of MySQL without installing the default connector and then I installed the 6.8.3 and the plugin for visual studio.

Then I can see the connection I made for my Entity model but when I'm about to choose the entity version, I get this message.

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**LATEST EDIT**

The bug has been fixed.

Chris' comment:

> 2015-11-07 and you can now get it all working without editing any
>   files or doing weird stuff. Use the MySQL for Windows installer and
>   include the Visual Studio support and the latest Connector.Net. Be
>   sure to update after installing and you will get the latest of each
>   (1.2.5 and 6.9.8). Use NuGet to install EntityFramework, MySql.Data,
>   and MySql.Data.Entity. Finally, built and enjoy code-first reverse
>   engineering goodness by adding an Ado.Net Entity Model.

**Original answer**

I found out it's a bug from MySQL.

[Here's](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,603916#msg-603916) the link explaining a workarround.

> On your machine where VS 2013 is installed, VS plugin (1.1.3 GA) and
>   Connector/Net
>
> Close all VS instances before doing the steps.
>
> On a Windows Explorer window go to this path or wherever you installed
>   you Connector/net binaries
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net
>   6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\
>
> Copy the file:
>
> MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
>
> And paste it to this folder
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
>
> If it asks you to overwrite it please do so.
>
> You'll need admin rights in order to overwrite the file.
>
> Then you can try again to generate the script for your model.
>
> It is important that you have the 1.1.3 version of the VS plugin
>   installed since this workaround is for that.

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, so I downgraded to entity framework 5 until they fix this.

**EDIT**

Finaly, it works now.

I had to add the 3 following DLLs :

- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net
  6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net
    6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Web.dll

Then I changed the EntityFramework part in the web config to :

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" /> 
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Don't forget to **REBUILD** and you should be able to create a entity framework 6 model with MySQL.

**IMPORTANT**

Make sure you have installed MySQL for visual studio **1.1.3** and MySQL connector .net **6.8.3**

Comment: I also had to had MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll to the /bin folder of the project to get rid of the warning in your edit.

Comment: I had the same problem and I followed your answer step by step and it works now.

Comment: I needed to also NuGet MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity (version 6.8.3.2) for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, that was what i needed. One note thought, i just downloaded the latest versions as mentioned in http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264 and the versions were 1.1.1 for the VS plugin and 6.9.5 for the connector. I can verify that these steps were needed for these versions too.

Comment: Thanks! Same issue exists ith MySQL for VS 1.2 and .Net Connector 6.9.5. I included Nuget packages for EntityFramework, MySqlData, and MySql.Data.Entity, because I could only get EF5 support until I added those Nuget packages.

Comment: Verified working with MySQL for VS 1.2.3, MySQL connector .net 6.9.6, and also the 6.9.6 nuget packages.  If you used the all-in-one installer, you may need to reinstall the standalone installer for connector because it was newer as of this comment.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: 2015-11-07 and you can now get it all working without editing any files or doing weird stuff. Use the MySQL for Windows installer and include the Visual Studio support and the latest Connector.Net. Be sure to update after installing and you will get the latest of each (1.2.5 and 6.9.8). Use NuGet to install EntityFramework, MySql.Data, and MySql.Data.Entity. Finally, built and enjoy code-first reverse engineering goodness by adding an Ado.Net Entity Model.

Comment: @Chris can you please copy this to abswer, Icamed here 3 times before I expanded comments and find solution

Comment: @adopilot I think Marc updated his question with a working solution but I added my answer as you requested, since some people may be looking for a NuGet-only solution that doesn't require assembly references outside NuGet.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.4.2 , and MySQL for Visual Studio installation (with MySQL installer or standalone installer) fails.
I tried to do this workaround ==> https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85908&thanks=3&notify=195 but the installation of MySQL for VS is still rolling back at 90%. 
Please help, I'm struggling to Update my Model from my Database since 3 days :/ I did every single steps described in this comment but nothing changed.
No MySQL Database option shows up when I click on "Update model from Database" on the new connection window. @Chris some help pls ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière my comment is for VS 2015. Sorry :(

Comment: No problem, I came accross my issue ;) Thanks :)

Comment: Days of searching and trying, this finally helped me... THANKS

Comment: The only thing that did for me was give me all sorts of data connectors: ODBC DataSource, Microsoft Access Database File and Oracle Database. Not one has anything to do with MySQL

Answer (score 11):

Solution in 2017

Install Nuget Package:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.9.9
```

Install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6
  - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Changes in Web.Config

```
<EntityFramework>
```

to:

```
<EntityFramework codeConfigurationType = "MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```

Add (** your information **):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="**YourContextName**" connectionString="server=**xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**;port=3306;user id=**your user**;password=**your password**;database=**your database**" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

**Restart Visual Studio**

My Settings:

 - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

 - Dot Net Framework 4.5.2

 - Asp.Net MVC 5.2.3.0

 - MySql Server 5.6

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.4.2 , and MySQL for Visual Studio installation (with MySQL installer or standalone installer) fails. I tried to do this workaround ==> bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85908&thanks=3&notify=195 but the installation of MySQL for VS is still rolling back at 90%. Please help, I'm struggling to Update my Model from my Database since 3 days :/ I did every single steps described in this comment but nothing changed. No MySQL Database option shows up when I click on "Update model from Database" on the new connection window. @Chris some help pls ?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is still a problem for you, guys, but none of the above solutions worked for me... until I found this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

After applying the patches (for both VS2013 and VS2012), I got VS2013 working wonderfully with EF6 for MySql.

ps. Package versions installed (from NuGet):
EntityFramework - 6.1.3 (03/10/2015)
MySqlData - 6.9.6 (02/24/2015)
MySql.Data.Entity - 6.9.6 (02/24/2015)
MySql.Web - 6.9.6 (02/24/2015)

NuGet does the job right and updates Web.Config accordingly, filling the "entityFramework" section with whatever needed.

For VS2013, it simply goes from "Not Working at all" to "Fully functional".
For VS2012, it makes it possible to use "Code First from Database", which was not available before applying the patch.

I wish I had found this about 10 days ago, so hope this may still be of some help.

Comment: This worked like a charm... Thanks a lot! had been struggling to get it work since 3 hrs...

Comment: For publishing my source i need to do something of particular? Or can I go for a simple publishing? The future client machine it will be correctly or i need apply some patch also there?

Answer (score 3):

For me reinstalling MySQL and using the installed connector version as a reference in Visual studio worked!

Steps:

1. Reinstall MySQL Tools with the latest stable MySQL connector for windows.
2. Add this 3 files as reference in Visual Studio:
3. MySql.Data.dll
4. MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
5. MySql.Web.dll
6. Modify following Web.config from

   ```
     <providers>
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
   ```

To:

```
 <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
</providers>
```

Make sure your connection username/password/db name are correct or Visual Studio may crash. (Happened with me.)

Answer (score 1):

My was facing the same issue.

I did the following: 

1. Install MySQL for Visual Studio from: 

   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

2. Install MySql.Data in my project 

3. Install MySql.Data.EntityFramework in my project

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the latest dot net connector for my sql ?
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html
or
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
depending your context.

Answer (score 0):

**2015-11-07 Update**

The bugs are fixed and you can now get it all working without editing any files or even referencing assemblies outside of NuGet. You simply have to install the right thing and add the right NuGet packages. Here's how:

Use the MySQL for Windows installer and include the Visual Studio support and the latest Connector.Net. Be sure to update after installing and you will get the latest of each (1.2.5 and 6.9.8).

Then, use NuGet to install EntityFramework, MySql.Data, and MySql.Data.Entity.

Finally, build and enjoy code-first reverse engineering goodness by adding an Ado.Net Entity Model.

Answer (score 0):

i found this on the [mySQL Bucktracker](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163)

> Try the following workaround....
>
> Run the following command on the MySQL DB and then try if this works.
>
> set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'

I also added the following assemblies:

- EF6 as Nuget package
- MySQL.Data
- MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
- MySQL.Web (not sure if really needed)

Answer (score 0):

FYI for everyone using a multi-project solution, if you can't run your GUI project due to problems with finding/loading MySql EF6 provider, like:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.(...)'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455747/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name/).

Although it's about SqlServer the problem might be the same: if only one of your projects handles the DB operations, then most probably you added Nuget References to `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity` and `EntityFramework` to that project. Since `MySql.Data` and `EntityFramework` are used directly by the code, the build process is smart enough to copy them to output folder, and to copy it second time to the GUI project's output folder as well.

However, since `MySql.Data.Entity` is referred to only by the `app.config` or `web.config` **text file**, the build process thinks that this reference is not needed (**the code** does not use it!) and strips it away, and you won't see `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll` in GUI project output dir, and this causes the GUI project to be unable to find that provider.

So - two options - ensure that something copies that DLL there as a part of build process (i.e. pre/post build event, deployment package builder, CI task, human task, whatever), or just make a direct reference to the assembly in your DB/EF6 project.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late in party. But I had same issue in Visual Studio 2019. I tried to install the MySql Connector and also the MySql for Visual Studio but it did not worked.

What worked for me is

1. I installed the development version of the [MySql for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) version 2.0.5. (Do not forget to click on development releases if you are using the above link I mentioned)
2. I installed following nuget packages `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` which normally installs many other packages including `MySql.Data`, `mysql.sata.entity.EF6` etc.
3. I installed [Connector/NET 8.0.26](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and EF6 with windows form application.
Connector/NET 8.0.26