# Could not find a compatible provider for entity framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following project in Visual studio 2013 ultimate using MySQL 5.6.17

1. New project: ASP.net webforms application

   - NuGet EntityFramework
   - NuGet MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity
2. Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model
3. Code First from database
4. Choose data connection
5. Choose your version (Entity Framework 6.0 is selected and grayed out).

This is giving the following error message:

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection.

What is the cause and how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have the [latest version of the MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) installed? You can also install `MySQL.Data` [via nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.8.3).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206184/cant-use-a-mysql-connection-for-entity-framework-6

the answer is here.

Answer (score 0):

Install latest version of MySql OR
lower version of Entity framework 
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0

Comment: The prerequisites is Code First from database.   Code First from database asked for EF 6, does not allow EF 5. It asked for EF 6.  but then when I asked for EF 6, I get this error.

Comment: You can almost answer any question by changing the question to make it easier.  Downgrading your prerequisites should be the last resort.  Fortunately, I stuck with the prerequisites and I found the answer below.