# Use ADO.NET with MySQL in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ado.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to use ADO.NET with MySQL, so I’ve installed MySQL Connector and MySQL for Visual Studio:

[image: MySQL Installer window with MySQL Server 5.6.23, MySQL Workbench 6.2.4, MySQL Notifier 1.1.6, MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.3, Connector/NET 6.9.5 and MySQL Documentation 5.6.23, all for X86 architecture]

(I use Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10)
When I create a new ADO.NET, I don’t have MySQL:

[image: EDM Assistant window with connection choice window]

I don’t know how I can get MySQL to work with Entity Framework… I followed [a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio), but it doesn’t work.

Comment: *but it dosent work* can you elaborate?

Comment: I havent MySQL in my DataSource, so this tutorial dosent work ^^
I dont know how can i fix this sh**... !
I have the same screen :/

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206184/cant-use-a-mysql-connection-for-entity-framework-6)

Comment: Nop again, i havent MySQL DataSource : http://puu.sh/gM6ng/0e137a844e.png

Comment: I just downloaded Visual Studio 2013, and it work fine, i think it just VS2015 because its a preview...

Comment: MySql Connector does not support VS2015 yet. It will work on VS2013.

Comment: Same issue here. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520607/382515) I changed Framework from 4.5.2 to 4.5 and it worked. What a pain to find it!

Answer (score 7):

From this release:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-for-visual-studio/en/visual-studio-news-1-2-4.html
it is possible.

In fact, I followed, and installed MySQL connector for Visual Studio 2015 correctly:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Answer (score 3):

At the moment it is not possible. See [info posted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/04/29/entity-framework-and-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx) about EF 7 - Beta 4:

> **What’s Next**
>
> [...]
>
> **Providers**
>
> There is work underway to enable the following database providers.
>   We’ve also had contact with many other providers who are planning to
>   provide EF7 support.
>
> - SQLite (being developed by the EF team)
> - PostgreSql (being developed by the npgsql team)
> - MySql (being developed by the MySql team)

Comment: Providers

There is work underway to enable the following database providers. We’ve also had contact with many other providers who are planning to provide EF7 support.
•SQLite (being developed by the EF team)
•PostgreSql (being developed by the npgsql team)
•MySql (being developed by the MySql team)

Comment: @PHeiberg I get that its still in beta so there for not ready yet. But the connector is not getting registered with vs2015 for some reason. So I cant even use it with EF 6

Answer (score 3):

This combination finally worked for me:
[MySQL for Visual Studio](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) - v1.2.6
[MySQL Connector/Net](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/) - v6.9.8
(Visual Studio 2015 Community and Windows 10)

Solution Reference:  [MySQL Forumn - "Can't Create Datasource on VS2015"](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,648619,649199#msg-649199)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [NuGet package for MySQL For Entity Framework](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySQL.Data.Entities/)

In Visual Studio 2015:

- Tools
- Nuget Package Manager
- Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

Search for MySQL and install the desired one.
Rebuild and its ready

Answer (score 2):

I've been stuck with this issue many days
I tried to install MySQL tool for Visual Studio from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html)

Everything is working now, Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Just use the old way:

```
 var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
 var conn = factory .CreateConnection();
 conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
 var cmd = factory .CreateCommand();
 cmd.Connection = conn;
 cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
 .....
```

Of course put it all inside using, etc

Here is my provider and connection string

```
providerName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
connectionString= "Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=123456;Database=world;CharSet=utf8mb4"
```

I used Visual Studio 2015 RC Version 14.0.22823.1 D14REL, MySQL.Data Version 6.9.6.0, Windows 8.1 x64 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem but solved it

- by running `odbcad32.exe` in windows\system32 directory and
- Adding `MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver` and
- then pick Data Source in `VS2015 .NET` Framework Data Provider for ODBC