# Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Runtime'

Tags: c#, .net, gac

I'm trying to install the Autofac nuget package in my project using the command

```
Install-Package -Prerelease Autofac
```

but it fails with the error

```
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Runtime'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
```

I've tried re-installing .NET Framework 4.5.2 (which is the version my project targets) but got the message ".NET Framework 4.5.2 is already installed". However, searching `C:\Windows\assembly\` for `System.Runtime.dll` doesn't find any exact matches (although there are a few instances of `System.Runtime.ni.dll`, which (seem to indicate) that they are really the same assembly...).

What can I do about this?

[image: project config]

**Update:** apparently I was confused about the location of the GAC. [Amy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47589/amy) enlightened me, and searching in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` instead I *do* find `System.Runtime.dll`. Why doesn't Visual Studio?

Comment: what is your project targetting?

Comment: @DanielA.White: As the question states: .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: did you verify the project properties? is it referencing a subset of the framework?

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes, I verified the project properties. No, it's not targeting a subset.

Comment: for completeness sake what kind of project are you targetting?

Comment: `c:\windows\assembly` is not the GAC anymore.  The GAC is in `c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly`.  The former was used in early .Net versions.

Comment: @DanielA.White see update.

Comment: @Amy: Thanks for that info! This gets even weirder by that, though - `System.Runtime.dll` *is* present in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\`!

Comment: Try adding the reference to the project manually, then use Nuget to install Autofac.

Comment: That's a very confusing error message since the GAC isn't used to resolve references at compile time. Visual Studio *should* be looking under `C:\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies` but that location shouldn't be referred to as the Global Assembly Cache.

Comment: @Amy: That got me past `System.Runtime.dll`, but then I got the same error message for `System.Threading.dll` instead. Of course, I could just do this for all the necessary assemblies, but I'm worried that a) it won't be portable to the other devs' machines or to the CI environment, and b) that the underlying issue will cause more problems later on. I'd rather actually understand and solve the problem.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem.

Found the solution here: https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/issues/18

To fix it, I added `<Reference Include="System.Runtime"/>` to the .csproj
file for the project, rebuilt it and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

> Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

That is an *excessively* unhelpful error message.  It not only doesn't describe the real problem, it also leads you drastically astray to find a workaround.  An assembly reference for a .NET Framework assembly must **never** come from the GAC.  The kind of failure modes when it does can be exceedingly [nasty to diagnose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/17034).  Reference assemblies must come from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies directory.

Looking at the .nuspec file for the Autofac nuget package you are trying to install, it supports two distinct targets.  One is for DNXCore version 4.0.10-beta-22816.  Hopefully you are not using it, that project is changing rapidly.

The other is .NET Portable, profile 259.  Which allows your project to target .NET 4.5.x, Store, Phone80 and Phone81.  What the blunt error message is telling you is that it has trouble finding that profile.  Use Windows Explorer to have a look-see, the profile is stored in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile259 directory.  It has the required System.Runtime.dll *reference assembly*.

Well, surely it awol, I can't guess at the underlying reason.

They did make subtle mistakes in the .nuspec file.  Do consider a more stable release of Autofac, you probably don't want to be a beta tester.  And don't target 4.5.2, there is no point to that.  It doesn't add anything interesting and forcing your user to update his .NET install is not very reasonable.

Comment: This is a, for my understanding, very helpful writeup - thank you! I do, however, have a `System.Runtime.dll` in the directory you indicated. Might there be something wrong with it? How do I know? I managed to get out of my immediate problems by recreating the project files from scratch and copying the code files from a backup.

Comment: If recreating the project fixed the problem then you don't have a problem with the reference assemblies.  Very hard to guess what could have gone wrong, you'll definitely want to run some integrity tests on your disk drive I'd say.

Comment: I and another user hit this problem reproducibly with a different package _SerilogTimings_ - worked around it by manually adding the reference, installing the package, then removing it again. Seems like a tooling issue with project.json-based packages.