# Install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.3.0.0-rc1-final into Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a class library for the new Microsoft Identity model but am being beaten back by an odd error.

If I create a regular C# Class Library (not a PCL) and attempt to install `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.3.0.0-rc1-final` via Nuget it goes so far, chokes, rolls back and then displays the following error:

> Failed to add reference to 'System.Runtime'. Please make sure that it
>   is in the Global Assembly Cache.

I know that this is a pre-release version of the library but this cannot be such a radical idea that I'm trying to achieve here.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the target framework of the class library?

Comment: I've tried with 4.5.1 and 4.5.2, same problem

Comment: The package supports 4.5.1 according to the nuspec file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519339/install-package-failed-to-add-reference-to-system-runtime is a similar issue where the OP solved it by recreating the project.

Comment: After having issues with the main project I create a new, completely clean solution containing just a single Class Library project - same result. Will try another laptop to see if it's a configuration issue

Comment: Tried on a different system, fully patched and all updates applied - same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue and [confirmed by Microsoft](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/783#issuecomment-210698897). It leads to [this NuGet issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2193).

A workaround, according to the comments, is to install *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore*, which is the RC2 equivalent. From what I can find this hasn't been officially released yet, and you might need to build from source.

Comment: Oh the joys of using prerelease software ;-). I think I'll have to keep the Identity stuff in the main MVC project for the time being. I'm considering just using MVC5 instead - but that will put me behind the curve in a few months. Decisions, decisions....