# How do I set up Entity Framework 6 to work with MySQL ready database (database first)?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

I have an existing remote mysql database.
Adding new ado.net entity data model and following the gui only offers microsoft sql server client.

Please help.

Comment: Did you install MySQL for VS and MySQL connector? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: both of them installed and it still does not show the mysql option, any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I am trying to remember b/c this happened with me too a while ago and VS started to show MySQL connector in EF import popup after I put some connection settings and MySql providers in web.config.  I will update when I remember exactly how it was fixed.

Comment: Perhaps try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206184/cant-use-a-mysql-connection-for-entity-framework-6