# I can't update my edmx since the Entity Data Model Designer is unable to open it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer

Hi everyone and thanks for taking the time to see my question.

I'm running VS 2017 with Entity Framework 6 and asp.net MVC and have to add some field to one of my Entities.

I added the corresponding fields in the database, but when I open the edmx file nothing shows apart the message "Entity Data Model Designer is unable to open this file." and it proposes me to open it in XML editor, but I have not the "Update model from Database" option when right clicking on the XML file.

Is anyone knows what causes this ?

Comment: Also seeing your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47115135/861716) I advise you to re-generate the EDMX from the database.

Comment: I'd recommend the same. Either you can see what's causing the issue and fix it by modifying the XML directly or just re-generate the EDMX entirely

Comment: Okay, how do I do that please ?

Comment: When I'm right clicking in the edmx Design surface I only have the option "Validate"

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer (not an edit in question), to learn more see [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came accross my problem. I searched for like 5 hours how to make a new database connection and realised I had no option with MySQL connection. So I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206184/cant-use-a-mysql-connection-for-entity-framework-6) and it led me on the good path. After, I found [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85908) cause I weren't able to install MySQL for Visual Studio. I followed these two steps:

- Download and install the MySQL for Visual Studio component without the MySQL installer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=469617)

  - Download and install the "Connector/NET" V6.9.10.  "mysql-connector-net-6.9.10.msi" [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html)

After that I started Visual Studio and the Design Surface showed up well, and I was directly able to Update my model from the Database :D

**EDIT:** I just saw that MySQL for visual studio wasn't installed properly. In fact, it rolls back up at the end of the installation, and I have no Mysql Database option on the "new Database connection" window :/ Does somebody know what this is about ?

**EDIT SOLUTION** Turns out that I had installed Visual Studio on an other disk than C: and mysql for visual studio Installer didn't like that. Now I see "MySql Database" in the list when adding a new connection.