# .edmx showing in xml not in diagram format (mvc 4)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I format my computer and install the entire enviroment again, but I can't see the data model diagram. I mean, I open the data model (edmx file) and I see all the DB tables and DB information in an XML file. Not the diagram in edmx format.

I installed vs2013 sp1, mysql 6.3 , my sql connector 6.9.9

I don't know what I am missing. Can you help me?

Without that I cannot update the model.

Comment: Try right clicking on the `edmx` in solution explorer and selecting Open With…. In the dialogue select designer (there will be multiple options and I cannot recall the exact wording). And set make that default.

Comment: when i click on model(edmx) in my solution  its popping as " .edmx is  not installed" .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146591/i-cant-update-my-edmx-since-the-entity-data-model-designer-is-unable-to-open-it

Comment: i have reinstall VS 2013 many times with EF 6 but still when i click edmx model it is showing the same alert as " make sure your (.edmx) installed " . help me with this issues .