# Mysql Entity framework 6.X not working with Visual studo 2017

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to connect to mysql using Entity framework in VS 2017.
 Entity framework 6.X  is disabled as shown in image.
Also When I am trying to click next button nothing happen (no error but not loading databases tables) [image]

I am able to connect SQL server database from VS2017. 
Entity framework 6.X option is enabled for sql server and working OK.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't use MySQL that often, but you might have an outdated MySQL connector installed. Check here if this page helps you out: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: thanks @H.Lowette I already have latest MYSQL connector from the same link. But its not working. I am not sure why EF6 is disabled in case of MYSQL

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218078/2343739)?