# Problem with entity framework 6 and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

Today i faced strange problem.
When i try to use Entity Data Model Wizard it crash on that moment when i click next or prompt error that i dont have Entity framework 6
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3ahd.png)

i look for some help in stackoverflow but all of the topics are pretty old and use diffrent version of database and connectors.
I follow instructions on every anwsers in that topic:[Can't use a MySQL connection for entity framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206184/cant-use-a-mysql-connection-for-entity-framework-6)
But still no results.
My spec:

- Visual Studio 2017
- Mysql server 8.0.12
- MySql for Visual Studio 1.2.8
- Connector/NET 8.0.12

Does somebody try to use framework on this versions ? 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL VS integration: [bug 91195](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91195).

Some other users have posted workarounds that they've found at that link. You may need to wait for Oracle to release a VS addin that doesn't crash.

Comment: Thank you.I search a little and i find a way to make it work