# SoapException System.Data.SqlClient missing or not registered / loaded

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I had to move an old existing application to a new application server (Windows 2012). Unfortunately, when starting the application and searching for an entity, it shows the following error message:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider
>   with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is either not registered
>   in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See
>   the inner exception for details. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable
>   to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be
>   installed.

Do you know why this is happening?

- Do I need to install something so that the System.Data.SqlClient is available?

I checked the connectionstring and it looks like this:

```
<add name="<connectionname>" connectionString="Data Source=<server\instance>;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Connection Timeout=180;Application Name=app_trace" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Additional info:** we use EntityFramework 6

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** Do I maybe need to install Microsoft SQL-Server on the new application server? If yes, which features do I need to install?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455747/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name

Comment: hi @codroipo thanks for your comment. entity framework is installed correctly in the solution as the application works fine on the old app server. we've deployed the same working version on the new app server and there it doesn't work so i guess it has something to do with the application server installation rather than the application itself