# Is it possible to call an Entity Framework Data Access Assembly from Python?

Tags: c#, python, .net, entity-framework, python.net

I'm experimenting with using Robot Framework for testing .NET applications.  It uses Python so I've been using PythonNet to call methods in the .NET assemblies.  Now I've struck a problem:  Calling an assembly that calls down into an Entity Framework-based data access assembly.

I'm not calling the data access assembly directly, but the assembly that uses it.  However, I'm getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No Entity Framework provider found
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
>   Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section
>   of the application config file.

I've created a similar test project in C# which does not include an EntityFramework section in the config file and it works, so I know I don't need a config file to use Entity Framework.

Another Stackoverflow question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777085/216440), suggested that it was necessary to reference the EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.  I tried adding the following to my Python code:

```
clr.AddReference("EntityFramework.SqlServer")
```

(note that the path to the .NET bin folder has been added to the Python sys.path already)

This didn't make any difference, I still got the same error.

Does anyone know how to add a reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll in Python or, alternatively, whether it's definitely not possible to call a C# assembly that uses Entity Framework from Python?

**EDIT:**

Here's the full code that I have so far:

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\...\bin\Debug")

clr.AddReference("SchoolGrades")
clr.AddReference("DataAccess")
clr.AddReference("Models")

clr.AddReference("EntityFramework")
clr.AddReference("EntityFramework.SqlServer")

from SchoolGrades import SchoolRoll
from DataAccess import SchoolContext
from Models import Student

connectionString = r"Data Source=(LocalDb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=DataAccess.SchoolContext;Integrated Security=True"
context = SchoolContext(connectionString)
school = SchoolRoll(context)

student = Student()
student.StudentName = "Python Student"
school.AddStudent(student)
```

It fails with the error above after the last line.

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry, looks like I've wasted your time.  I tried pasting the code above into a .py file and running it, and it worked perfectly.  I had previously just been working it out interactively and had been getting the error above.

At least if anyone else wants to know if it's possible to run a .NET assembly that uses Entity Framework from Python, the answer is yes.

**EDIT 3:**  Turns out the references to EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer are not needed; the script works without them.

Comment: How are you adding the connection string to the context?

Comment: the way the paths are treated in interactive python and script mode are slightly different:

Answer (score 1):

The way the paths are treated in interactive python and script/module mode are slightly different:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/98