# how to make connection between the provider and connection string web.config visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

**web.config for visual studio 2013  **
i have tried lots of things but still get the same error what should i do ? that's the error i get

[image: the error]

the web.config code the default connection string

[image: i commented it]

the connection string i wrote

[image: the new one]]

i know the problem is in provider but i don't know what to do ?
that's the whole problem and the images of the web config code ?
any ideas ?

Comment: Did you read and verify what is said in the error message of your first screenshot ? Says something about no provider found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455747/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name)

Comment: A quick search on your error messages brings up a bunch of people who solved your problem by reinstalling EntityFramework.

Comment: Please post the code and error messages in your question, not to external sites. The SO search doesn't search external sites and when your link expires your question will not make any sense. Also, post code and messages as text, not screen captures.

Answer (score 0):

First off, why are you using VS 2013 when VS 2017 is available? Get VS 2017 and .NET Core.

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Second, what? What are you trying to do here? You can't connect to a server you're not the root user for. If you're attempting to connect to anyone's server but your own, you're going to have a bad time. A [connection string](https://www.topfloorsolutions.com/Dictionary/Definition/Connection%20Strings) is provided by the business hosting your server. For example, Microsoft Azure provides each of their cloud server subscribers with connection strings to connect to that server. In web.config, if I recall correctly, you simply scroll to the top of the page and paste the connection string into the connection string element. Then enter your password and name into the string where the password and name placeholders are.

Comment: i am  trying to make music app store using mvc4 the problem is i can't make connection between my database and the app