# WCF Service with Proxy cannot connect to EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf, proxy

I want to implement a WCF service with a proxy. The service and proxy are situated in 2 different projects. The entityFramework is in the Service project. And in the proxy's app.config I put the connection string as below:

```
<add name="foodOrderEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/foodOrderEF.csdl|res://*/foodOrderEF.ssdl|res://*/foodOrderEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\foodOrder.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

[image: the map of the solution]

But when I try to invoke the method with the service test client I get the following exception:
**@"The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."**

Please anyone could tell me how can I set up the connection string in such a way that the proxy project serviceHost can access the database successfully? Or do I need to crate another project independently for the EF object and then add reference?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys I found another post that is relevant to this issue. 
[No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455747/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name?rq=1)

after all, what I need to do is just to add the reference of EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll to the proxy project.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Nuget Entity Framework download in the service project. I'm pretty sure both the Service project and the ADO.NET Data layer project should have the Entity Framework installed.