# error 0152: Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to run a test project, to debug the code, but the moment its trying to save data to a table in database its giving this error:

**Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  MSLEntities.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.**

1. Made sure that both are using the same version of EF (6.0). Check.
2. Tried to enter the provider name in the connection string but
   already using providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
3. Tried removing and reinstalling EF using PM console. Check. Manually
   removed Ef references and readded them. Check.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455747/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I was missing a value in connection string tag once I added it with the provider a System.Data.EntityClient, it worked.